# Python eval in def with passed in func: map okay but list comprehension fails on namespace

Tags: python, namespaces, eval

I am trying to grasp the nuances of python namespaces. Why does eval() over a list comp fail when the enclosed func is passed into the function containing eval? All of these run2x versions work except for the last one run2g.

```
def sub2(var2):
    var2 += 1
    return var2

def run2c():  # This works by retrieving sub2 from globals
    print('comp', eval('[sub2(n) for n in (1,2,3)]'))

def run2h(func):  # Partial fix but cannot access globals in eval()
    print('arg comp', eval('[func(n) for n in (1,2,3)]', locals())) 


def run2h(func):  # Fails again on func
    print('arg comp', eval('[func(n) for n in (1,2,3)]', globals(), locals()))

def run2g(func):  # This fails to use func in locals
    print('arg comp', eval('[func(n) for n in (1,2,3)]'))  # NameError: name 'func' is not defined




def run2a():
    print('base', eval('sub2(1)'))

def run2b():
    print('map', list(eval('map(sub2, (1,2,3))')))

def run2c_():
    print('comp', eval('[sub2(n) for n in (1,2,3)]'))

def run2d(func):
    print('arg', eval('func(1)'))

def run2e(func):
    print('arg map', list(eval('map(func, (1,2,3))')))

def run2f(func):
    print('arg plain', [func(n) for n in (1,2,3)])

def run2g_(func):
    print('arg comp', eval('[func(n) for n in (1,2,3)]'))  # NameError: name 'func' is not defined



if __name__ == "__main__":
    run2a()
    run2b()
    run2c()
    run2d(sub2)
    run2e(sub2)
    run2f(sub2)
    run2g(sub2)
```

Python 3.6

Comment: @user1753919: That's not quite the same. There, the `eval` is inside the list comprehension. Here, the list comprehension is inside the `eval`. That changes how the variable resolution plays out.

Comment: I don't understand: "There, the eval is inside the list comprehension" Where do I have an eval inside a list comprehension?

Comment: You don't. The other question (linked in a now-deleted comment) did.